# For the interface between two linear, isotropic, homogeneous dielectric materials with no free charge, does $E$ remain continuous?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, boundary-conditions, dielectric

The title basically says it all. Does the normal component of the electric field stay continuous across the interface of the two dielectrics? My intuition is that it would not stay the same as there is most likely some difference in values between the two materials. However I wanted to see others thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

No, if the permittivities are different. The relevant boundary condition is the continuity of the normal component of $\vec D$. For linear and isotropic media, this means that the relation between the normal components of $\vec E$ on the two sides of the interface is $\epsilon_1E_{1n}=\epsilon_2E_{2n}$.